# C# Consumir Webservice

Tags: c#, webservice, aeat-sii

Recientemente hice una utilidad para mandar facturas al sistema SII de hacienda usando el webservice de hacienda.

En visual studio cree una referencia al servicio web
https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl

De esta manera, comodamente accedo a los métodos y puedo hacer el envío de datos deseado.

en el fichero app.config tengo añadidas estas lineas

```
<client>
      <!--Facturas emitidas-->
          <!--Entorno Real -->
          <endpoint address="https://www1.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding2"
                contract="WsSiiFraEmi.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidas" />
    </client>
```

Ahora ocurre que los del pais vasco hacen los mismo pero la url del servicio web es distinta. es la siguiente
http://www.bizkaia.eus/ogasuna/sii/documentos/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl

los metodos y funcionalidades es la misma solo que cambia la direccion del webservice y su endpoint.

mi pregunta es, he de crear una nueva referencia al nuevo servicio web o se puede aprovechar la referencia web ya establecida y cambiar solo el endpoint address??

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Gracias

Comment: Depende. Si necesitas manejar ambos en la aplicación, lo mejor es crear una referencia nueva. Si te refieres a poder cambiar de uno a otro simplemente modificando el app.config, yo diría que debería funcionar. De todas maneras, es una prueba sencilla de hacer :)

Comment: Hola Pikoh... gracias lo primero. Mi necesidad es tener una aplicación que bajo un parámetro use un servicio u otro sin tener que duplicar el código :-)

Comment: El parámetro donde iría? Se configuraría en la propia aplicación?

Comment: Si. eso habiá pensado. Crear un parámetro sencillo en el app.config para que cada uno decida donde ha de sincronizar...

Comment: En ese caso podrias modificar en el app.config el endpoint  directamente en tu aplicacion dependiendo de la opción seleccionada. Nunca lo probé, pero creo que debería funcionar. Mira [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1357240/579895)  por ejemplo.

Comment: Si. eso es lo que había pensado, pero mi duda es si debo o no añadir como referencia los dos servicios web... De todas formas esta url que me has pasado está genial, justo buscaba como hacerlo.

Comment: Como te he dicho, yo creo que si modificas el endpoint en la configuración, con una referencia sería suficiente. Pero no puedo asegurarlo, tal vez alguien pueda. Si lo pruebas y funciona, añade una respuesta para que otros puedan verlo :)

Comment: Si.. Justo lo estoy probando cambiando solo el endpoint. pero ahora da error de servidor, parece ser que esta caido el entorno de pruebas... pero en cuanto acabe con esto lo publicaré, claro que si.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para cambiar entre el entorno real y el de pruebas, sí es posible hacerlo sin modificar las referencias. También se puede hacer hacer para el SII de Navarra, pero con los vascos, al utilizar distintos namespaces en los esquemas, no te va a funcionar. Nosotros, además de modificar la dirección, hemos añadido un EndpointBehavior para hacer un "replace" de los namespaces. Mira https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-or-modify-messages-on-the-client. Suerte.

Comment: Gracias por la info. Peibol.. voy a ver si lo consigo y si lo entiendo.

Comment: No lo he conseguido hacer. Creo que no entiendo bien como hacer el endpoingbehavior.

Comment: Hola Peibol, podrias compartir como lo has hecho?... gracias...

Comment: Aquí tienes un ejemplo en el se graba en un fichero log casi todo lo que pasa por el webservice: https://github.com/airdoct/DemoBehavior . Espero que te ayude